# My Mobile Service Company Gifted me a Car, Is it permissible for me to use/sell?

Tags: halal-haram

I got a call from my Mobile Service Provider that I won a Car as a gift. I haven't received the car but wanted to ensure if it is Halal to use it. I did not voluntarily get into the competition, the mobile company did everything I think after looking at my mobile service usage. Kindly let me know if I can sell the car and use the money or am I allowed to use it as a means of transport too!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why not.  It doesn't really fall under the rulings of gambling since you didn't pay any fee with the express purpose of participating in the lottery.  It is, quite simply, a gift, and you can do with your gift as you please.

Answer (score 0):

Receiving this gift will be haram if the you have invested Time/Money/Effort in hopes of winning the car. But since the only stipulation was that you are a customer, then you are entitled for the car. God knows best.

Answer (score 0):

i think if you just randomly got a call and won a car, then it should be okay, but if it was some lucky draw and a hit or miss case, then i am not too sure since that might come under gambling.

if you were not aware of it in advance or hoping to get it, and got it now, take it as a gift from an entity that does business with you and is giving you a gift as a customer relationship effort.

the basic idea is that everything that a person acquires should be acquired in exchange of due effort and not on some lucky draw where everyone invests in the hope of winning and may or may not win. Gambling messes up the personality of the human being and makes him relatively unstable as he tends to bend towards shortcuts in life and making 'easy money' and the addiction of winning or losing money simply based on chance can destroy not just the individual but also the person's families.

Answer (score 0):

I will focus on question only(ie is it halal or haram to accept it may be totally different)

If it is somehow related to your purchase of their services or goods, then this gift becomes part of your purchase.

Just like 'we should clarify deal before leaving counter' , you should first clarify any such contract. If they don't, directly or indirectly, prohibit your single use or sale etc then you are free. Otherwise you must respect deal/contract or rejecting the deal is your right.

Ofcourse, Allah knows the best.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be halal.There is no informations in any books as I looked but if you want to make sure give the 1/5 of the price to poor people.It is formally called khomse.Note that there is no need but if you want to make sure that it is halal do that.

Comment: Please elaborate more on this "khomse" you're talking about.

Comment: @Amir Syafrudin.It is different between shie and sonnie which one are you?